# Register and unregister onSharedPreferenceListeners

Tags: android, listener, sharedpreferences

I have two question about registering/unregistering *OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* objects:

**Question 1**: do I need to invoke *registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* and *unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* on the same instance of *SharedPreferences* object in order to properly register and unregister for changes on shared preferences or is it suffiecient to invoke the two methods on two *SharedPreferences* instances obtained for the same preference file?

**Question 2**: the *OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* instance passed to *registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* must be exactly the same instance passed to *unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener*, i.e. I can not create a new instance *on the fly* with *new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() { ... }* for the two methods?

**Question 3**: can I register more than one *OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* objects?

Answer (score 2):

Your interface that is a listener for your SharedPreferences is merely a class that 'implements' OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener, this means the class can handle the message the SharedPrefs will send it.

Therefore whatever *instance* you register, you will need to use the same reference to deregister it.

Q1) YES , you unregister before your sharedpreferences go out of scope i.e. register in onCreate unregister in onPause

Q2) Yes you can't, making a new instance makes a whole new object.

Q3) You would have to check [the source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/SharedPreferences.java) implementation to see if the class keeps a list of registers or if it just allows one. (having reg and unreg makes me believe you can set multiple listeners but check)

Comment: Ok, about Q1, if I'm in a service, I should save a reference to the shared preferences object and to the listener in two instance variables in the onCreate method, register the listener in onCreate and unregister it in onDestroy, right? But is it really necessary to save a reference to the *SharedPreferences* object to avoid it going out of scope and keep receiving preference changes' notifications?

Comment: My doubt is "do I always get the same object when I retrieve a *SharedPreferences* object with a method like *getDefaultSharedPreferences* or do I get a new instance every time?" Because if I receive always the same it should not be necessary to save a reference to it to unregister the listener, unless the fact that the retrieved instance goes out of scope makes me not receiving notifications of preference changes anymore.

Comment: Here *http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html* at section *getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)* it says that this method returns always the same *SharedPreferences* object, but the question about what happens when all the retrieved instances go out of scope remains.. if you registered some listeners will they still be called or does the only instance of *SharedPreferences* get garbage collected as soon as all the references to it go out of scope?

Comment: @GianniCostanzi You ask to many circular questions at once, slow down. If the SharedPreference instance has listeners attached to it (i.e. your Activity) it cannot get GarbageCollected because .. it still has references to it!

Comment: I'm sorry if I've asked too many questions..I thought that if I register a listener to a *SharedPeeference* instance it is the shared preference object that has a reference to the listener, not vice versa, so the shared preference object can be garbage collected if it goes out of scope.

Comment: @GianniCostanzi It is, no so the SharedPreference can't be garage collected until your listener doesn't have any other references (I'm not an expert on the subject tbh). I can only recommend further reading: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html or watching: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: I think that given the fact that *getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)* always returns the same *SharedPreferences* object for a given String (i.e. preference file), it means that a reference to that instance must be hold into a static variable of *SharedPreferences*, so even if all of your references get out of scope, there is always a reference to the *SharedPreferences* instance of a particular preference file after you've retrieved it for the first time.